# Sql query with input parameter by string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need sql query (maybe dynamic?) which will process my input parameters:

- `@Data` – data,
- `@Fields` – column names,
- `@Types` – data type

Rows separating by standard character. Column separating by TAB.

Input data:

```
DECLARE @Data nvarchar(max) = N
   '1             cat fish
    2             dog meat
    3             chicken corn
    4             cow herb
    5             pig feed
    6             human              all'

DECLARE @Fields nvarchar(555) = N'ID Object  FoodType'

DECLARE @Types nvarchar(555) = N'int nvarchar(36)      nvarchar(36)'
```

Result that I need:

```
ID  Object  FoodType
1   cat     fish
2   dog     meat
3   chicken corn
4   cow     herb
5   pig     feed
6   human   all
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (id int, name  varchar(50))

insert into @t (id,name) values( 1    ,'cat fish')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 2    ,'dog meat')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 3    ,'chicken corn')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 4    ,'cow herb')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 5    ,'pig feed')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 6    ,'human all')


select 
    case when CHARINDEX(' ',name)>0 
         then SUBSTRING(name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',name)-1) 
         else name end  Object , 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',name)>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name)+1,len(name))  
         ELSE NULL END as FoodType
from @t
```